# How to write SQL UPDATE statement to update simultaneously?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to write SQL statements to switch the values of `CompanyName` in `table1` so that all rows currently having the value `'Linens and Things'` will have the value `'Lamps and Lighting'`, and all rows currently having the value `'Lamps and Lighting'` will have the value `'Linens and Things'`.

My table currently looks something like this:

```
id  CompanyName
--- ----------------------
1   'Linens and Things'
2   'Linens and Things'
3   'Lamps and Lighting'
4   'Lamps and Lighting'
5   'A Different Vendor'
```

After the update, it should look like this:

```
id  CompanyName
--- ----------------------
1   'Lamps and Lighting'
2   'Lamps and Lighting'
3   'Linens and Things'
4   'Linens and Things'
5   'A Different Vendor'
```

Comment: You can use [database cursor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28databases%29)

Comment: I added some example tables to clarify what you mean, if I got it wrong please update the tables so we can better answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this is what you want:

```
UPDATE table1
SET CompanyName = CASE WHEN CompanyName = 'Linens and Things' THEN 'Lamps and Lighting'
                       WHEN CompanyName = 'Lamps and Lighting' THEN 'Linens and Things'
                       ELSE CompanyName
                       END
WHERE CompanyName IN ('Linens and Things','Lamps and Lighting')
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're inversing the values, you'll need to proceed by 3 different updates (3 steps) as follows;

Step1: Change the values of existing 'Linens and Things';

```
Update table1 set CompanyName = "x"
where  CompanyName = "Linens and Things"
```

Step2: Modify the vendors 'Lamps and Lighting' to 'Linens and Things';

```
Update table1 set CompanyName = "Linens and Things"
where  CompanyName = "Lamps and Lighting"
```

Step3: Modify the vendors which were initially 'Linens and Things' to 'Lamps and Lighting';

```
Update table1 set CompanyName = "Lamps and Lighting"
where  CompanyName = "x"
```

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL's UPDATE statement has a FROM clause that lets you compute a table before you update it. For this case, we can compute the new name as `AlternateCompanyName` and set `CompanyName=AlternateCompanyName`.

```
UPDATE table1
SET CompanyName = ComputedTable.AlternateCompanyName
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        CompanyName,
        CASE
          WHEN CompanyName = 'Linens and Things' THEN 'Lamps and Lighting'
          WHEN CompanyName = 'Lamps and Lighting' THEN 'Linens and Things'
        END AS AlternateCompanyName
    FROM table1
) AS ComputedTable
JOIN table1 ON table1.id = ComputedTable.id
WHERE table1.CompanyName IN ('Lamps and Lighting', 'Linens and Things')
```